# Need to restructure git project and rename branch

Tags: git, architecture, refactoring, rename, rebase

i have a git project structured as following:

```
Main (which acts as production)
Develop (which acts as pre prod environment and is branched from Main)
Several feature branches (which are branched from Develop).
```

The usual workflow is create a new feature branch from develop, than merge it there, test it and later merge into Main to go to prod.

Now i want to add a stage environment which will be placed between Develop and Main, ideally the new structure will be the following :

```
Main ( prod )
Stage ( pre prod )
Develop ( test environment )
Feature branches
```

The problem is that i don't know how to refactor the project with git.

My idea would be to rename locally the `Develop` branch into `Stage`, delete the old remote and push the new one.
Than create a new `Develop` branching from `Stage` and from there create the several feature branches.

1. Would this be the correct approach?
2. Right now i have several feature branches that are branched from develop, what happens to them if i delete develop and i recreate it? Should i somehow rebase them into the new develop ?
   Can you provide me with some git instruction on how to set up all of this if you think it's the good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Branch is just a pointer. As such you can easily do what you want in a few steps.

```
git checkout Develop # checkout current Develop branch.
git pull # make sure you are up-to-date
git checkout -b Stage # just create a stage branch from current Develop.
# now you have your Stage branch with full history of Develop branch.
```

from now on you can keep development on the Develop branch and merge back to Stage branch, for staging. and then as you wanted merge to main(prod) from Stage.

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.
I think i'm not getting something, with your solution the hierarchy would be the following :

Main => Develop => Stage 

Because you have branched Stage from develop no ?
I would like the other way around, so my feature branches will first merge into Develop and later into Stage before going into Main

Comment: it is exactly what you want. You need to understand what git branch represents. It is just a pointer.

when you do `git checkout -b Stage` both branches Develop and Stage are identical. Then you start new feature. You will be doing from Develop. By creating a new FB. Once done, you will merge your PR to Develop, which will make your Develop branch one commit ahead of Stage. Then you can merge/cherry-pick that commit back to Stage and then from Stage to Master. Do you need visual representation ?

Comment: see my updated reply

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the detail explanation and the visual representation that helped a lot.
I thought that creating a branch from a branch would mean some sort of hierarchy between the two.
Meaning i have branch A and from there i create branch B. This would mean that branch B is son of branch A and i would have to merge there. So branch B should merge to branch A and not the other way around